# Mailto body links destroy Outlook signature

Tags: email, outlook, mailto

The body part of mailto links destroys our Outlook Signatures. Is there any way to solve this problem, so that I can insert some body text while keeping Outlooks Signature intact?

To clarify...

say I have a mailto link like this:

```html
 <a href="mailto:example@example.com&body=customText">send email</a>
```

When the user clicks the link, Outlook opens up a new email with everything intact... except the Outlook Signature! How do we solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is creating the new mail message with the signature but content of your 'body' parameter overwrites the whole content of the message. So you can not see the signature.

Comment: Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40379699/9990676