# Is it possible to preserve signature using mailTo?

Tags: javascript, email, outlook, mailto

For eg if I use "mailto:abc.com?body=Hello All" then the signature part is not preserved in the default outlook client.

If I remove the body part from the above the signature is preserved. Is there any way I can preserve signature even if I use body in mailTo ?

P.S. I am using javascript here to invoke mailTo on button click.

Answer (score 2):

This is an outlook related issue, and there is no workaround to solve this. Outlook's default behavior is to replace the entire body including the signature.

For reference, see [this post](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26410679/HTML-Mailto-link-does-not-add-my-signature-in-Outlook.html).